# Как решить проблему с установкой пакетов apt?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

Ubuntu 20.10.
Изначально попытался:

```
sudo su
apt install fastboot
```

Выхлоп следующий:

```
Ошб:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libunwind amd64 10.0.0+r36-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libbacktrace amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libsparse amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libf2fs-utils amd64 8.1.0+r23-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libutils amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libziparchive amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:7 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libcdt5 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:8 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libcgraph6 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:9 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libpathplan4 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libgvc6 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:11 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libgvpr2 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:12 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 liblab-gamut1 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:13 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 graphviz amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:14 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 fastboot amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Игн:15 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 sqlite3 amd64 3.33.0-1ubuntu0.1
Ошб:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 sqlite3 amd64 3.33.0-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-external-libunwind/android-libunwind_10.0.0+r36-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libbacktrace_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libsparse_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-extras/android-libf2fs-utils_8.1.0+r23-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libutils_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libziparchive_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libcdt5_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libcgraph6_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libpathplan4_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libgvc6_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libgvpr2_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/liblab-gamut1_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/graphviz_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/fastboot_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.33.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить некоторые архивы; возможно, нужно запустить apt-get update или попытаться повторить запуск с ключом --fix-missing?
```

Теперь так выходит при установке любого из пакетов.

apt-get update:

```
Сущ:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease
Игн:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Сущ:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Игн:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Игн:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                  
Игн:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                               
Ошб:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release                                                                                                                                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Сущ:8 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease                                                                                                                       
Ошб:9 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release                                                                                                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Сущ:11 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian hirsute InRelease                                                          
Ошб:12 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Сущ:13 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                             
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово                                       
E: Репозиторий «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release» больше не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release» больше не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release» больше не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release» больше не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
```

--fix-missing:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  kbuild libgsoap-2.8.104 liblzf1 libvncserver1 module-assistant virtualbox-source
Для их удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты:
  android-libbacktrace android-libf2fs-utils android-libsparse android-libunwind android-libutils android-libziparchive android-sdk-platform-tools dmtracedump graphviz libcdt5 libcgraph6 libgvc6 libgvpr2
  liblab-gamut1 libpathplan4 sqlite3
Предлагаемые пакеты:
  gsfonts graphviz-doc sqlite3-doc
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  android-libbacktrace android-libf2fs-utils android-libsparse android-libunwind android-libutils android-libziparchive android-sdk-platform-tools dmtracedump fastboot graphviz libcdt5 libcgraph6 libgvc6
  libgvpr2 liblab-gamut1 libpathplan4 sqlite3
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 17 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 1 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 1 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 2 902 kB/2 932 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 12,6 MB.
Хотите продолжить? [Y/n] y
Ошб:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libunwind amd64 10.0.0+r36-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libbacktrace amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libsparse amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libf2fs-utils amd64 8.1.0+r23-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libutils amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 android-libziparchive amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:7 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libcdt5 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:8 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libcgraph6 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:9 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libpathplan4 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libgvc6 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:11 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 libgvpr2 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:12 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 liblab-gamut1 amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:13 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 graphviz amd64 2.42.2-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ошб:14 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 fastboot amd64 1:8.1.0+r23-8
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Игн:15 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 sqlite3 amd64 3.33.0-1ubuntu0.1
Ошб:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 sqlite3 amd64 3.33.0-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-external-libunwind/android-libunwind_10.0.0+r36-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libbacktrace_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libsparse_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-extras/android-libf2fs-utils_8.1.0+r23-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libutils_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/android-libziparchive_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libcdt5_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libcgraph6_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libpathplan4_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libgvc6_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/libgvpr2_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/liblab-gamut1_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphviz/graphviz_2.42.2-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-platform-system-core/fastboot_8.1.0+r23-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Не удалось получить http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.33.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Пробовали сделать то, что написано в самой нижней строке?

Comment: Да, не помогло.

Comment: Что конкретно пишет, когда вы выполняете то, что написано в самой нижней строке?

Comment: тоже самое что и до этого

Comment: Самая нижняя строка предлагает выполнить совершенно другую команду, которая никак не может писать то же самое. Всё-таки выполните её.

Comment: apt-get update- прерывается сразу же с сообщением "E: Не удалось получить..." аналогично и с -fix-missing

Comment: Вот и покажите, что конкретно пишет, полностью без многоточий

Comment: У меня ограничение на 500 символов

Comment: У вас всегда есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1368605/edit) в вопросе

Comment: Вот теперь стало понятно. Поддержка Ubuntu 20.10 прекращена уже полгода назад, и все репозитории были удалены, и архив тоже почему-то не создали. Из этого следует печальный вывод, что устанавливать пакеты теперь невозможно

Comment: @АндрейСеменов, дык, у 20.10 срок поддержки закончился… или переходи на свежий релиз или на меняй репы на старые.

Comment: @Fat-Zer а конкретно для 20.10 никаких «старых» реп я не смог найти, на old-releases.ubuntu.com пусто

Comment: @andreymal, http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ — там же где и все

Comment: @andreymal, [неужели](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy/)?

Comment: @Fat-Zer ваша ссылка нерабочая https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1H2f.png

Comment: @andreymal, [УМВР](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGEbi.png) o_O может у тебя браузер/провайдер шалит?

Comment: @Fat-Zer забавно, я перебрал все восемь IP-адресов из DNS-записей old-releases.ubuntu.com, и на двух ссылка не работает — 91.189.91.123 и 2001:67c:1562::25 (видимо, это один и тот же сервер). Интересно, как это понимать

Comment: @andreymal, да, похоже проблема на их стороне,  [баг](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1956164) уже зарепортили три дня как, но пока ни какого ответа…

Comment: @Fat-Zer спустя месяц так и не починили :(

Comment: @andreymal,  мда... что-то они не чешутся даже...

Answer (score 0):

т.к. ОС старая, раширяем репозиторий

sudo sed -i 's/cosmic/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

обновляем

sudo apt update

устанавливаем

sudo apt-get upgrade